# How much different shape from two RAM at different speed?

Tags: memory

I was looking two rams both are identical specification except "speed". For example, I saw Samsung 1066mhz and Samsung 1333mhz look like totally identical except stickers.

I couldn't find any tiny shape difference except stickers on the ram.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The similar look is that they are both the same type, probably DDR3. Theoretically the different speeds with be limited to which ever is slower, the motherboards capacity or slowest ram card. However, some machines can handle mis matching and some can’t. In cases that it you are able to get it to work, it can still potentially run into other issues in the future. I heard ram likes to work in pairs if you have more than a single card. Installing two matching speeds that are above your devices capability will give you similar problems.